# Batch commit docs to Google Firestore database, node.js and promise issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, google-cloud-firestore, batch-processing

I'm trying to loop through an array of transactions, then add each transaction to a batch to commit to my firestore database.

However, my function is finishing before the batch request is fulfilled and the transactions are written to my database.

I believe I need to use a promise to wait to commit my batch request, but I'm new to node.js and promises.

Wondering if anyone would be able to assist and point out where and how to use a promise in my code to ensure the batch request is fulfilled.

```
function saveTransactions(transactions)
{
  var batch = db.batch();
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < transactions.length - 1; i++)
  {
    var transaction = transactions[i]
    var data = {
        description: transaction.description,
        amount: transaction.amount
    };
    var docRef = db.collection('user_transactions').doc();
    batch.set(docRef, data);
  }
  return batch.commit().then(function () {
    return true
  });
}
```

Here's a link to Firebase's firestore and batch request documentation to give some context - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Comment: batch.commit().then(function() { // this is promise }) .then are the function which runs when the requrest is completed as per promise library.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop looks wrong.  It's not looping over an array:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
```

That is just going to execute the body of this loop once.  If you're trying to iterate over all the contents of the transactions, you probably want this instead:

```
for (i = 0; i < transactions.length; i++)
```

Comment: Sorry that was me testing my code, I've updated the question.

Comment: It looks like you now have a typo in your code.  Have you copied the exact code that isn't working the way you expect?  How are you calling the function?